# Excel 2010 calculate new value based on another cell's value

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Hope someone can help me here. Many years ago I wrote an entire ordering system for our horticultural company in VB 6 that functioned the same way I need my Excel spreadsheet to, but I no longer have the code or have a clue what I did.

Basically, we have a spreadsheet that on each row has the item number (ex. "12345", item description (ex. "Petunia Blue Frost"), the multiple that the item is sold in (ex. "100", "48", "288") and a column where a user can enter the quantity they'd like to order for each item. In my old VB system, whatever they put in the ordered qty field, it would automatically round it up to the next multiple. So, if the multiple was "100" and they put "1" in the ord qty, it would automatically round it up to "100"; if they put "101", it would round it up to "200".

How can I have Excel automatically do this, based on what the multiple is and what the ordered qty is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok, I kind of figured it out.  I can use the ceiling function.  If column C1 has the multiple (say 100) and column D1 has the ordered qty (say 52), column F1 has "=ceiling(D1,C1)" and it returns "100".  However, is there ANY way to have the function happen in D1 (so no new column is needed)?  I tried to put the formula in D1 and just get the REF# error.

Comment: What about `=IF(test,true_condition,else_false_condition)` ?
So..  Yours will be something like: `=IF(C1:D1>100,ceiling(D1,C1),"")`
You may also have to have a couple nested IFs to look for specific conditions.  If you have to use a lookup to pull say from a discount table, use `=VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

Comment: @KimJones You will probably find that Excel does not have that functionality without using an event in VBA. It sounds like you're asking for Excel to automatically round up input values to the next multiple. Excel formulas do not work this way. Most people would accomplish this with `=CEILING(D1,C1)` as you already stated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right calculation to accomplish what you need.

```
=CEILING( quantity / multiple ) * multiple
```

Example Data:

> `quantity: 101`
>   `multiple: 100`
>   `expected: 200`

Example:

> quantity / multiple = 1.01
>   CEILING( 1.01 ) = 2
>   2 * 100 = **200**

Comment: That doesn't work, and also doesn't address the problem. `=CEILING(D1,C1)` is the expected output. Even with your new edit, it's still incorrect.

Comment: @grovesNL I don't have MS Excel, I'm using Google Spreadsheet (witch is almost the same), can you please tell me why this doesn't work?

Comment: Simply for the reason that `CEILING` takes two arguments. `CEILING(value,multiple)` will do what the question asked, as written in the comment itself. The author doesn't want to use this - they wish to modify it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Excel formulas do not modify (in your case, calculate the CEILING) values in-place. You were likely modifying the text field in VB.

You can use VBA to handle the cell change event and calculate this, but this is probably not a  very good way to handle this. Using the additional column to perform `=CEILING(D1,C1)` is likely the better solution.

Comment: Might want to mention how to use VBA... such as a cell change event trigger without an infinite loop.

Comment: @PortlandRunner The worksheet change event can address that by checking if the value has already been converted to its `CEILING` equivalent - if it has, then do nothing (ie. no infinite loop). I still believe that the VBA event method is not a good way to handle this, because the original input is destroyed.

Comment: I think the change event using VBA is what I'd need (I want to change the original #) -- can someone help with the code (since "ceiling" is not a VB function) and with the infinite loop?  thanks!

Comment: You can easily write a `CEILING` function by dividing the original value by the factor, rounding to the nearest integer, then multiplying that by the factor. Alternatively, you can call Excel's function directly by using `WorksheetFunction.Ceiling` described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.ceiling.aspx